# In Scala what are the effects of incrementing a scope value in a foldLeft compared to an accumulator

Tags: scala

Scala what are the stack and runtime effects of incrementing a scope value in a foldLeft compared to an accumulator

```
        var counter = 0

        val filteredTransformedActivities: List[PushLeadActivity] = partitionRecords.foldLeft(accActivities)(

          (acc, record) => {

            if(isRtpRelevantActivity(record._2, subscriptionMetadata)){

                try {

                  val listItem: PushLeadActivity = transformer.transform(record._2, subscriptionMetadata).get

                  counter += 1
                  pushLeadActivity +: acc

                } catch {

                  case e: Exception => acc
                }
            } else {
              acc
            }
          }
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

The entire second argument to `foldLeft` is a `Function2` that has to modify the mutable variable `counter` somehow. If I remember correctly, this is implemented as follows:

- A synthetic closure-like object with a mutable member variable `counter` is generated
- This object is stored on the heap
- The function that is passed as second argument to `foldLeft` holds a reference to this heap-resident object, and updates its mutable variable `counter`.

The creation of this heap-resident synthetic object would not be necessary if you didn't use any mutable variables in the `foldLeft`. I assume that the introduction of this synthetic object will either have negative impact on performance (make it a bit slower), or no noticeable impact at all.

The `foldLeft` itself is implemented as a while-loop, so it is stack-safe, nothing terrible happens here.

I personally would advice to not bother modifying anything, unless you find the accumulator-version clearer (is it really that much clearer?), or you can show by profiling that this mutable heap-resident variable has some dramatic negative impact on performance.

Comment: Thanks for the learned answer, please clarify "his doesn't look like it could have any non-negative". I will endorse non the less.

Comment: @RubberDuck Agreed, too many double-negations. Rewrote it, hopefully it's a bit clearer now.